# Number of transactions using @transactional in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, transactional

I am a beginner i spring-mvc-hibernate and i have a controller which have many calls to daoimpl methods in my spring mvc which are annotated by @Transactional does it make round trips for every method or does it make a single one?

Code looks like this : Hibernate is used to process all calls

```
CustomerEntity customerEntity = (CustomerEntity) customerService.getCustomerFromLeadId(id);
AddressEntity resAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getResAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
AddressEntity offAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getOffAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
List<KeyContactsEntity> listKeyContacts = keyContactService.getKeyContactOfClient(customerEntity.getSomeId());
List<PropertyEntity> listProperty = propertyService.getListOfProperty(customerEntity.getSomeId()) ;
customerDto = masterService.setEntityValues(customerDto,customerEntity,resAddressEntity,offAddressEntity,listKeyContacts,listProperty);
```

Comment: Roundtrips? Roundtrips where? All the annotated methods would start (and finish) their own transaction naturally.

Comment: Transactions don't magically group totally different queries into a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the transaction works is simple. If from a component Controller, that is not transactional, you invoke a method from a service, that is transactional, your service method create the transaction, and then when the method it finish, since your controller is not transactional, the transaction is finish and it´s committed.

So in your case that you´re calling all those services from a non transactional component you create a new transaction for every one of them which is wrong because that´s means that if something goes wrong in the third service you cannot rollback the two previous

```
class Controller {

    //New transaction
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = (CustomerEntity) customerService.getCustomerFromLeadId(id);
    //New transaction
    AddressEntity resAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getResAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
    //New transaction
    AddressEntity offAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getOffAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
    //New transaction / if something goes wrong no rollback for previous transactions
    List<KeyContactsEntity> listKeyContacts = keyContactService.getKeyContactOfClient(customerEntity.getSomeId());

}
```

If you want group all your service transaction in just one, you need wrapp all of them into a "facade" component with @Transaction

```
   @Transactional
   class FacadeService {

    //New transaction
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = (CustomerEntity) customerService.getCustomerFromLeadId(id);
    //Reuse transaction
    AddressEntity resAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getResAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
    //Reuse transaction
    AddressEntity offAddressEntity = (AddressEntity) addressService.getOffAddress(customerEntity.getSomeId());
    //Reuse transaction / If something goes wrong rollback of everyting
    List<KeyContactsEntity> listKeyContacts = keyContactService.getKeyContactOfClient(customerEntity.getSomeId());

}
```

Comment: all the methods that i have mentioned are annotated with @transactional in daoImpl. and what i am doing is the methods i called are all service methods which internally calls dao methods and return the data. so in that case will every method make a roundtrip to db or all the data will be fetched in one db transaction?

Comment: If the answer was useful vote it and mark it as finish please.

Answer (score 0):

By default only one transaction will be used.

You can read up on transaction propagation to understand fully here:

[Spring transaction propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation)

By default Spring will use the "Required" strategy, which means "support current transaction, create a new one if none exists". Many other strategies exist to suit your needs.

A typical "gotcha": Spring transaction management is proxy-based, so it will only be triggered when you call a method sitting on another class than the caller, i.e. no transactions are triggered when you call methods on the same class.